# Detect number of touches

Tags: ios, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I have a problem, In my app I have a Label and when I touch on it a method is fired, I implemented with `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, the problem is that when I touch, the method is fired (everything is working) but I want when I touch once again another method to fire. How to do that???

Comment: Are you asking about how to keep a running total of how many times `touchesEnded:withEvent:` was called or to detect how many fingers were used in a touch?

Comment: You can use a global counter, create a method which updates counter and fires appropriate method depending the value of counter.

Comment: Look, the app is launched and when I press on UILabel an action is fired, now I want when I press once again (just one touch), onother action to fire....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about changing state after a touch.  Most people would use just a boolean, or an integer enum to keep track of what state they're in, and fork the code accordingly.  However, if you need to discern between a tap, a double tap, a triple tap, a pan, or press and hold, then you should look at gesture recognizers, and in particular, watch the WWDC video where they were introduced (2011?).

Comment: You told that most people would use just a boolean, can you please  tell me how to do that???

Comment: Define a boolean variable in your controller (or worst case, as a global):  BOOL state = NO;  When you get the first touch, check to see if state == NO, if so, set state to YES, and execute the code to run on the first touch.  The next time, state will be equal to YES, so execute the code for the second condition.  You can reset back to the original conditions by resetting state to NO.

Answer (score 0):

> I want when I touch once again another method to fire.

`-touchesEnded:withEvent:` and the other touch handling methods will always fire in response to touch events -- you can't change that. What you *can* do is look at the touch in your implementations of those methods, figure out which method you want to handle that particular event, and then call that:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches
           withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    switch ([touches count]) {
       case 1: [self oneTouch:touches forEvent:event]; 
               break;
       case 2: [self twoTouches:touches forEvent:event]; 
               break;
       default: [self moreThanTwoTouches:touches forEvent:event];
               break;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you don't have to decide which method to call based on the number of touches -- that's just an example. You can use any information at your disposal, such as the state of the object handling the touch event.